# top n in DolphinDB SQL statements

Tags: sql, dolphindb

The following SQL statement in DolphinDB database

```
n=10000
x = select top n * from bn_1m_spot
```

returns the following error message:

```
Syntax Error: [line #2] integer constant expected after keyword top
```

Is there a way to use a variable after keyword top in DolphinDB SQL?

Comment: Usual SQL answer is dynamic SQL, but perhaps this page https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?Metaprogramming.html will help with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `top` clause must be used with a constant integer. If you do need to specify n dynamically, please use function `sql` to construct a sql statement.

sql(select=sqlCol("*"), from=bn_1m_spot, limit=n).eval()